# nuxt.js – is Server Rendered and SPA mutually exclusive?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

In the nuxt documentation section "Production Deployment" it says:

*Nuxt.js lets you choose between three modes to deploy your application: Server Rendered, SPA or Static Generated.*

Does that mean that with nuxt SPAs cannot be (initially) server rendered at all? And on the other hand: What if an application consists of multiple server rendered pages, which each need behave like a single page application i.e. be a rich client? Is that not achievable with nuxt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. SPA cannot be server rendered, if you need server render, use server rendered mode.
2. Server will render the first page, the rest of app will just like SPA.

Note that you have to use vue-router to navigate page to enable SPA feature